# Pandas area plot-axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,2,3], 'col_2': [3,4,5],
  'date_col': ['2014-12-15','2015-11-07','2016-01-10']})
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col']).dt.date
df.plot.area(x = 'date_col', y = ['col_1', 'col_2'])
plt.show()
```

It produces area plot as intended, but there are more x axis labels then I need. I need only 3 labels as in dataframe. Any suggestions?
[image: plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `xticks` to the plot before showing it:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,2,3], 'col_2': [3,4,5],
  'date_col': ['2014-12-15','2015-11-07','2016-01-10']})
df.plot.area(x = 'date_col', y = ['col_1', 'col_2'])
plt.xticks(range(len(df.date_col)),df.date_col)
plt.show()
```

The desired output:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry it does not work, all dates are in one place, whole plot is distorted.

Comment: What do you mean by *all dates are in one place*? If the dates are close together, then you're likely to end up with labels that are stuck together. From the data you shared here, I was able to get what you described as your desired output.

Comment: appologies, your code works perfectly. I forget that I also have the following line in my code `df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col']).dt.date`

Comment: @user1700890, if this was helpful and solved your problem, please consider marking it answered. Thanks!